# Nginx as reverse proxy to Hudson-Logout issue

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, hudson

I have configured nginx as a reverse proxy to our hudson build server as follows:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  koala.proxy.internal;


location /hudson/ {
    proxy_pass         http://build.example.com/hudson/;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    }
```

The backend hudson server is configured to authenticate users with Active Directory using
the hudson active directory plugin.

Everything works fine, except that when I click the logout button, nothing happens, and
I am still logged in, wheras the expected behaviour is, I should be logged out and taken
back to the login page.

The request and response headers in firebug show these:
Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 01 Sep 2010 02:40:57 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: ACEGI_SECURITY_HASHED_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE=""; Path=/hudson
Location: http://koala.proxy.internal/hudson/
Content-Length: 0
Expires: Thu, 02 Sep 2010 02:40:57 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
```

Request:

```
GET /hudson/logout HTTP/1.1
Host: koala.proxy.internal
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722     Firefox/3.6.8
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://koala.proxy.internal/hudson/people/
Cookie: screenResolution=1280x720; JSESSIONID=8957FA425BC89DE784266DAACAD45135
```

Below are the headers from the hudson server, when I access it directly and click the logout button:

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Expires: 0
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 01 Sep 2010 05:00:33 GMT
```

Request:

```
GET /hudson/login?from=%2Fhudson%2F HTTP/1.1
Host: build.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://build.example.com/hudson/
Cookie: screenResolution=1280x720; JSESSIONID=105C0A7031B817E0321336310FC8D6E1
```

As I understand from the headers,when I click logout, the GET request should be for `"/hudson/login?from=%2Fhudson%2F"` and not for `"/hudson/logout"` , as is happening through the reverse proxy.

I have tried many things to get it working but to no avail.Would really appreciate if someone could guide me here.

Thanks,
Mogaroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may be facing similar issues, I solved my problem by adding '**add_header Pragma "no-cache"**' to my configuration.

http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2010/06/commong-nginx-configuration-options.html

Thanks,
Mogaroy